Должны ли незакавыченные кавычки наследовать внешний вид закавыченных?

«„Цыганы“ мои не продаются вовсе», — сетовал Пушкин.

Тут всё правильно.
Но что если указанное произведение надо упомянуть, в том же тексте, не цитируя его автора? Какие в этом случае должны быть кавычки: «такие» или „такие“?

«„Цыганы“ мои не продаются вовсе», — сетовал Пушкин. Продажи «Цыган», однако, резко повысились после ...


«„Цыганы“ мои не продаются вовсе», — сетовал Пушкин. Продажи „Цыган“, однако, резко повысились после ...



Может, надо такие рекомендации Грамоты использовать:

В русском письме наиболее употребительны следующие типы кавычек:
«елочки» (употребляются в печатных текстах);
„лапки” употребляются, как правило, в рукописных текстах).

Тогда лучше записать так (для печатного текста):

«„Цыганы“ мои не продаются вовсе», — сетовал Пушкин. Продажи «Цыган», однако, резко повысились после ...

Незакавыченные кавычки не должны наследовать внешний вид закавыченных. Всего-то важно учитывать, что они выступают не частью слова, а функциональным элементом письма. В тексте есть иерархия кавычек, и её важно соблюдать, чтобы обеспечить читателю однозначное понимание написанного. В конце концов, вы ведь не станете писать с прописной буквы слово "бежал" с оглядкой на то, что в предыдущем предложении глагол "бежал" находился в первой позиции? Было и было. Никакого "наследования" в тексте не может быть.
